# How to end a parent Job when a child job fails

Tags: spring-batch

I have a Job that has a step that references another Job

```
<job id="childJob1" .....
  <step id="step1.1" ... />
  <step id="step1.2" ... />
</job>

<job id="parentJob" ...>
  <step id="step1" ..>
   <job ref="childJob1" />
  </step>
  <step id="step2" ..>
   <job ref="childJob2" />
  </step>
</job>
```

I implemented the logic so when **step1.1** fails, **step1.2** is not executed, and **child1** Job interrupts accordingly. However, I also need to get the whole **parentJob** interrupted when **step1.1** fails.

How can I promote the FAILED status from **child1** Job to either **step1** or **parentJob**, or accomplish the interruption of the whole parent Job?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What, exactly, do you mean by "interrupts"?  It ends?  Fails?  Pull the plug?

Comment: By "interrupts" I mean it can FAIL, so I can check for external dependencies (files, info in tables, etc., usually provided by third parties, in case they are missing -that's part of an established process here where I work) and try to run it again, so it can resume exactly where it failed.

Comment: I'm a bit confused.  If you run a child job from Spring Batch and the child job fails (BatchStatus = FAILED), the parent step will be marked as failed as well.  Is that not working for you?

Comment: I am, too. I just thought it would work exactly as you said, @Michael Minella, but it's not. As I've seen in the logs and by debudding, even if the child jobs fails (either by seting the ExitStatus in a listener or throwing a RuntimeException), the step in the parent Job ends up having a COMPLETED status, and the next step in the Parent Job is invoked as if nothing wrong had happened.

Comment: What is the **batch status** of the child job?

Answer (score 0):

I've been doing some research and found a way to accomplish this:

Using the [JobOperator](http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/reference/html/configureJob.html#JobOperator) interface, I could access to any job in the repository, so I injected a reference to it in a JobListener configured for my nested job.

When the nested job fails, it looks up the parent Job ID by using the **getRunningExecutions(parentJobName)** method. Afterwards, I can invoke the **stop(parentJobId)** method and fail the whole Job.

I guess there might be a better approach out there, but in the meantime, this is working fine.